# Solve 1st order ODE in using `scipy`

Tags: python, numerics, ode, scipy, differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following equation
$$
y(t)=-A\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}+B\cdot\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}\right)^{2}+C
\\
y(t=0)=y_{0}\\
$$
where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are positive numbers. The derivative at $t=0$ is also known but not really needed. I tried to solve it using `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` but all the tutorials I watched don't have the derivate in the function and I can't figure out how to decouple it.

Comment: Are you sure that an ODE model is appropriate? The description looks more like a PDE is required. Also, height as function of velocity seems a little suspect, are you sure of the left side?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its ok to describe the velocity as dh/dt
the change in height over time (dh/dt) is the flowrate(Q) [m3/s] by the crosssection area(A) [m2] and you get dh/dt=Q/A=-v[m/s]

As for the ode vs pde, the only derivative is water height by time to I think it is an ode

Now I've noticed I'm missing the minus before the derivative, not sure it changes anything tho

Comment: A,B,C just constants? Why not to solve the quadratic equation first to express y' = F(y), then go from there with any standard ODE method.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson
I only have first-order equations, its power of 2 not second derivative

Comment: @MaximUmansky
What do you mean?
I have B*(y'(t))^2+A*y'(t)+(C-y(t)), for when y=0 i can solve like that, but i want to plot y(t), or am I missing something

Comment: Okay; the too-small parentheses fooled me on casual reading (along with the claim that you needed two initial conditions).  I've fixed the parentheses for you.

Answer (score 1):

One preliminary comment is that supplying at the initial point both $y$ and $y'$ is redundant. If $y'(t_0)$ is given then obviously the ODE fully defines $y(t_0)$. On the other hand, if $y(t_0)$ is given then in general there are two different values of $y'(t_0)$ that satisfy the equation since the ODE can be interpreted as a quadratic equation for $y'$.

Extending this argument further, we solve for $y'$ in terms of $y$ and parameters $A$,$B$,$C$:

$$
y' = - \frac{A}{2B} \pm \frac{1}{2B} \sqrt{A^2 - 4 B (C-y)}
$$

There are two branches here, and each of them defines an ODE in the canonical form $y_t=F(t,y)$ which can be solved with any standard method. Below is a short Python code solving the problem for illustrative values of the parameters: `A=1`, `B=-1`, `C=1`, `y(0)=-100`. There are two branches of the solution, and in this situation, one would usually need to invoke some physics arguments to establish if both branches are meaningful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

#-parameters
A=1; B=-1; C=1

#-two branches
Fp = lambda t, y: -0.5*A/B + (0.5/B)*np.sqrt(A*A - 4*B*(C-y))
Fm = lambda t, y: -0.5*A/B - (0.5/B)*np.sqrt(A*A - 4*B*(C-y))

t_eval = np.arange(0, 10., 0.1)
solp = solve_ivp(Fp, [0, 10.], [-100.], t_eval=t_eval)
solm = solve_ivp(Fm, [0, 10.], [-100.], t_eval=t_eval)

plt.plot(solp.t, solp.y[0])
plt.plot(solm.t, solm.y[0])
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
I tried to supply as much info as possible,
but should have added that A, B, and C should be positive
which constricts my solution, at some points, it'll be ill-defined.
the solution should only be the declining one.

but much thanks!

Comment: @BackSpace42 Glad to hear it was useful. If this answer solved your problem then please go ahead and accept it.